# Apply data annotations validation to all properties of same primitive datatype in a viewmodel

Tags: c#, validation, data-annotations, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I searched google and SO for my scenario but not able to find an answer. I want to create a regular expression data annotation validation in a viewmodel class properties which are of `double` type. Since I have around 20 properties of type `double`. So I want to create a custom regular expression validation and apply to all double type properties without explicitly specifying on each property like:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]{1,6}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$", ErrorMessage ="Invalid Input")]
public double Balance { get; set; }
```

I am expecting thing like this:

```
[ApplyRegExpToAllDoubleTypes]
public class MyModel
{
     public double Balance { get; set; }
     public double InstallmentsDue { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: i don't think that is possible...

Comment: Ehrm... `double` is a number. Regular expressions are for strings. How does this work out for you? Your regex is validating that the input is a number with decimal point. But having `double` type of the property already does that for you - the framework does the checking. Why do you need regex on a double?

Comment: Also, are you sure you want `double` on `Balance` variable? I feel this is about money. And money are better represented by `decimal`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1165788/809357

Answer (score -1):

That's an interesting question. Here is how it can be done:

Define a custom `ValidationAttribute` and apply it at the class level by setting `AttributeTargets.Class`. Inside the `ValidationAttribute`, use reflection to get the `double` properties, then validate the value of each property. If any of the validations fail, return a validation failed message.

```cs
[ApplyRegExpToAllDoubleTypes]
public class MyModel {
    public double Balance { get; set; }
    public double InstallmentsDue { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class ApplyRegExpToAllDoubleTypes : ValidationAttribute {
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object currentObject, ValidationContext validationContext) {
        if (currentObject == null) {
            return new ValidationResult("Object can't be null");
        }

        var properties = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperties().Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(double));
        foreach (var property in properties) {
            //Here I compare the double property value against '5'
            //Replace the following with the custom regex check
            if ((double)property.GetValue(currentObject) < 5) {
                return new ValidationResult("All double properties must be greater than 5");
            }
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you apply a validation to all properties of type. But the question ask about regex validation on double (which makes no sense).

Comment: @trailmax the question is about applying validation to multiple properties without having to annotate every single property in the class. I didn't include OP's regex in my answer because it's irrelevant to the main point of the question (for all I care about the given regex could be invalid regex). And in general RegularExpression can be used to set some validation rules on a double type, so I'm not sure what your point is.